# Joomla: Post form fields from module to component

Tags: database, forms, joomla, joomla-module

I am a beginner to Joomla development. I have developed a rating module which looks as below.

[image]

I have managed to get the ratings from my database, but I do not know how to insert into the database when user clicks the vote button.

I have a form in my module which contains the four drop down boxes and a submit button (Vote). Now I am planning to develop a component in order to process this form data. How should I develop my component to process this? And what should be the form action in my module?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ajax is not needed. I just need to process this form data in the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create component
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1
Create module
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module

you must specify action of your module with JRoute
http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

look at component code example

```
$controller->execute( JRequest::getWord( 'task' ) );
```

so you must create controller and special task method for processing data

If you don't need component at all you can put logic in your module
In this way module should have form action to current page and process logic something like

```
$elements = JRequest::getVar('vote_data', array(), 'post');
if(count($elements)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I created the controller. But I do not know what to do next. Where to handle the post data?

Comment: I'd go for creating the functionality in the module instead. It's not worth to create a component with only one event unless you need to archive your pools or planning to add more functionality in the future.

Comment: To handle your post data use http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_JTable_class. Check-in, check-out is not required, just create you table schema, bind your post data, check it and store. After you load it you simply display it in you module.

Comment: Is it a good practice to post the form data to self i.e to module here? Is it secure? If so I would simply do that because I dont need any complex funcionality here. Just going to run an insert query.. thats it..

Comment: One more doubt.. Currently I have three hidden fields in my module.. 
1) option = com_mycomponent 
2) controller = mycontroller
3) task = vote
Now I have an entry point file where I create instance of controller class and then $controller->execute($task)
But I do not know what this execute method will do and I do not know where I should include that JTable class and do all my process of inserting into the database... 
Could you please help me?

Comment: When I post my form data to self, I get an error 500 - View not found. How to avoid this? I have SEF turned on. Will this be a problem?

Comment: does it work if SEF is turned off? If no I think you don't use naming conventions of component structure

Comment: You are getting view not found because option=com_mycomponent. You dont need to submit that or the controller or task if you submit to the module. Just post to the module like Fivell recommended above. Simply look for the post variables as part of the module code. If they are there, dump stuff in to the DB and display the results. If they are not there, display the form.

Comment: @brent: thanks. It is working perfectly now. But Is it secure and is it a good practice to post a form to SELF?

Comment: you should try to make your form variables names more uniq to avoid it processing by current component 
for example change "vote_data" to your module name

Comment: As long as you are sanitizing the input you should't have any problems. As Fivell mentioned it's also a good idea to make sure you are processing the right input. I use unique field names and I also include a salted hash to insure the input is coming from the module.